# Convert 2-digit date to year in the 1900s

Tags: postgresql, date

I am using the string manipulations functions in PostgreSQL 9.6 to convert a 2-digit text year into a 4 digit year. I am able to convert the string into a date and year, but the I keep getting years in the 2000s instead of the 1900s.

```
select extract(year from to_date('58', 'YY'));
```

This returns `2058` instead of `1958.`

Now all of my 2 digit dates are in the 1900s, but I cannot find a max function or parameter in the `to_date()` function that forces the date into the 1900s.

Anyone know how to change this behavior?

Comment: `select 1900+ '58'::int`

Comment: SELECT ('19' || '58')::int

Comment: Yeah, that make a lot of sense. I can use that. I thought there might be a better way, but this will totally work. Thanks so much for the idea.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Thanks for the tip. This is also a nice way to get around this  issue I was running into.

Comment: Please write up one or more of those solutions as an Answer, to be accepted so we can close this Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact behavior is defined [in the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

> If the year format specification is less than four digits, e.g. `YYY`, and the supplied year is less than four digits, the year will be adjusted to be nearest to the year **2020**, e.g. `95` becomes 1995.

Bold emphasis mine.

Since 2058 is closer to 2020 than 1958, the first one is the result you get from `to_date('58', 'YY')`.

There is currently no setting to override this behavior. You have to provide the desired century explicitly if you disagree with the default. Similar to [what Haleemur commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332965/postgresql-convert-2-digit-date-to-year-in-the-1900s/46333219#comment79626774_46332965):

```
SELECT to_date('19' || <2-digit-year-variable>, 'YYYY');
```

But [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) takes `text` input, not `integer`. Integer input would raise an exception like:

> ```
> ERROR:  function to_date(integer, unknown) does not exist
> ```

And if by:

> convert a 2-digit text year into a 4 digit year

... you mean a 4 digit *text* year, it's cleaner to use `to_char()`:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('19' || '58', 'YYYY'), 'YYYY')
```

[`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) can return text in variable formats (unlike [`extract()`, which returns a `double precision` number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)).

If the input is valid 2-digit strings (nothing but exactly 2 digits), a simple concatenation does the job, too

```
SELECT '19' || <2-digit-year-variable>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Good to know that this is the default behavior now, so I am ready for the next time I have to do something similar.

Comment: @krishnab: The answer you accepted is actually a bit misleading. Integer is uncalled for and incorrect.

Comment: Oh okay, I can ask them to fix it. I accepted that one because they were the first to answer with a good answer, even though your answer was more detailed and apparently more correct. Thanks for the comment though, I did not catch that bit about the integer.

Comment: @krishnab FYI, Stack Overflow allows you to change your acceptance to a different Answer, as you see fit.

Comment: @BasilBourque okay thanks. I did just that. Thanks again for the answers Erwin.

Answer (score 1):

to convert a 2 digit year stored as text to a 4 digit year like 19xx you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ('19' || '58')::int
```

or user klin suggested

```
select 1900+ '58'
```

Comment: would you mind removing the `::int` piece at the end of kiln's answer. seems like that bit is not necessary, as per Erwin's answer below. Just wanted to make sure we were as accurate as possible.

Comment: The bit you removed (`::int`) made it worse. If '58' comes as `text` variable (or quoted string literal),  `select 1900+ '58'` is not possible (`ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer + text`), and if it's a numeric variable or literal (unquoted), the cast to integer in the first term is uncalled for. If we can rely on valid 2-year text input, the shortcut is simply `SELECT '19' || '58'`. Throwing `to_date()` into the mix has the collateral benefit that invalid years (like 'b9') would raise an exception. The cast to integer serves the same purpose, but it needs an explanation to go with it.